# Как открыть доступ через интернет по адресу удаленной машины http://localhost:4001 (вместо localhost ай пи адрес)

Tags: node.js, localhost, node-modules, wamp-server

на удаленной машине открываю адрес http://localhost:4001/
и получаю ответ. 
Что нужно сделать для того, чтобы можно было открыть этот адрес через интернет .

Естественно чтобы открывать ресурс через интернет, я меняю localhost на адрес моей машины, доступный в сети.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wamp сервер предназначен для локальной разработки и отладки. Его не 
   нужно использовать для создания сервера из своей машины.
2. Чтобы порт на вашей машине был доступен через интернет, у вас должен быть
   внешний статический ip адрес. Это обычно отдельная платная
   услуга у провайдера. Если у вас просто динамический ip(типа 192.168.1.68, 172.10.10.10) то ничего не выйдет т к в интернет вы попадаете через шлюз провайдера и видны под его ip. Это можно проверить на myip.ru например.

Comment: я запускаю wamp на удаленной машине, на которой и стоит внешний статический ip адрес

Comment: я попадаю через свой комп к каталогу /www/ на удаленной машине , по адресу http://[ip_adress]/index.html

Comment: wamp стоит на 80 порту, если зайти со своего компа по адресу http://[ip_adress]/ , то я попаду на главную страницу wamp сервера

Comment: запускаю js скрипт через Node.js , который стартует его на 4001 порту. Я могу зайти через http://[localhost]:4001/ и получить ответ, но как мне получить ответ, заходя с моего компа по внешнему адресу удаленной машины? Если вводить http://[ip_adress]:4001/, то я не получаю ответ

Comment: Если у вас действительно белый айпи, попробуйте telnet <ip address> 4001. Порт должен прослушиваться. Если порт не прослушивается значит фаервол на удаленной машине не дает к порту доступ.

Comment: в бранмауэре открыл входящие соединения для tcp и udp для порта 4001 и ноль эффекта

Comment: да вообще в принципе ничего не открывает через мой комп домашний, кроме ip_adress/ , всё что я ввожу с добавлением порта - ip_adress:port/ у меня не открывает, хотя на удаленой машине открывает всё.

Comment: Какой ip адрес на удаленной машине?